# Should I put "Research Assistant" as my position on my CV if I'm a MS student?

Tags: masters, cv

I'm a post-grad MS student doing my thesis in a lab. Should I put this on my resume/CV or leave it out? If so, how do I word it?

Answer (score 7):

In most places RA is a specific title/job, given by the university. It isn't something you can assume or claim on your own. Give a description of what you do, not a title. It might be considered fraud if anyone thought to check.

Answer (score 3):

My answer will focus on the US, it might be different where you live. Some countries consider PhD to be an employment (not student) position, for example, so it can definitely make a difference.

In the US, a Research Assistant is an official research position that you are hired and compensated for. You would only list this if you were actually hired by the university to work as a Research Assistant.

The work done in your thesis is not the same thing. An RA's research may or may not relate to their thesis, it doesn't actually matter in this case. The thesis itself is part of your work as a student, not an RA.

If you were hired as an RA, you can list that as a separate employment position. If you just did a thesis as a student, that is part of your education and *not* an RA position.

Comment: So in my field there was no distinction between thesis and RA work, the two are expected to be interchangeable assuming you were being payed by the advisor.

Comment: Were you being paid by the advisor? If so, can you explain exactly what compensation you received? Additionally, is there any paid position with the title of "Research Assistant"?

Comment: @FourierFlux, I doubt that is true throughout your field. More likely at your university and, perhaps, a few other places, but not a general thing. Maybe limited to just the lab you worked in due to some funding arrangement.

Comment: RA work is always assumed to be towards your thesis because the grant is targeted towards completing a particular project which is the accumulation of thesis work. I acknowledge that it can be different somewhere else.

Comment: @FourierFlux Just because there isn't a distinction between thesis work and RA work while being paid as an RA doesn't mean you should say you had an RAship just because you worked toward a thesis.

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just disputing the notion that RA and thesis work are separate when it's not the case, at least at my university.

Comment: There are different systems around the world, so it's hard to give a general answer. My experience with the US system is to treat them separately. If I see a CV with a Research Assistant position, I would assume they had a funded position as a university employee. In my case, that meant I received a salary and worked on external projects separate from (and sometimes unrelated to) my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your advisor if your department recognizes you as a formal research assistant. If yes, indicate it; if not, don’t.